# why i am getting none.? printing output of one method inisde another method

Tags: python

```
class company:

    def __init__(self,name,lname):
        self.name = name
        self.lname = lname


    def fullname(self):
        print(f'{self.name} {self.lname}')

    def display(self):
        print(f'{self.fullname()}')

emp1 = company('john','king')
emp1.display()
```

output is

```
john king
None
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because the method `fullname` is not returning anything (`None`). To use the function like you expected, instead of printing the string, return it.

```
def fullname(self):
    return f'{self.name} {self.lname}'
```